# Google Map v2 with SupportMapFragment not working properly when exporting Android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an activity using Google Map v2. I use an extension of SupportMapFragment. 
When deploying it on the device(galaxy tab 2) in USB debug mode it works perfectly, but when trying to export it as a signed application package(.apk) and install it on the same device the map is displayed as empty. No exception is thrown.

In the manifest file I have the following permissions set:

```
<permission android:name="my.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"> 
<uses-permission android:name="my.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES">
```

Here is the code of my extension of SupportMapFragment:

```
public class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment{
 private MapViewCreatedListener mapViewCreatedListener;
 public void setMapViewCreatedListener(MapViewCreatedListener mapViewCreatedListener){
  this.mapViewCreatedListener=mapViewCreatedListener;
}

 // Callback for results(is used to add behavior to the map in the main activity,e.g. map click listener)
 public abstract static class MapViewCreatedListener {
  public abstract void onMapCreated();
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle           savedInstanceState) { 
  View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);              

  //Notify the view has been created
  if( mapViewCreatedListener != null ) {
   mapViewCreatedListener.onMapCreated();           
  }
  return view;
 }  
}
```

Comment: Create a new API key as per your package and add into manifest.xml

Comment: pbm is with your hash code that u use to export application.hash code that you used to generate the api key is should be used while exporing the application.

Comment: @SharadMhaske is right, you should check weather you put right hash code because when you export your app it use different key to sign

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by using wrong API key(generated from SHA1 of the debug certificate). 
It worked after using a new one generated for the key pair which was used for signing the application.